# What language does the narrator speak in From Dust?

Tags: from-dust

Is it any specific language? The people themselves and their culture seem to be intentionally generic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The language you hear the tribes speaking in From Dust is a mix of **[Swahili](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swahili_language)** and **[Malay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malay_language)** languages.

<strike>[Source](http://www.xboxliveaddicts.co.uk/index.html/_/questions-and-answers/summer-of-arcade-from-dust-trivia-r3480)</strike> may be broken; other sources: [1](http://www.ggsgamer.com/2011/08/01/10-things-you-probably-always-wanted-to-know-about-from-dust/) [2](http://www.lazygamer.net/24/10-things-about-from-dust-you-didnt-know/) [3](http://www.onlinecenter.pl/Artykuly/Summer-of-Arcade-2011-Trivia.html)

All sources are based on the "Top 10 things Ubisoft Montpellier think you ought to know about this game".

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry if I'm late, but I do confirm there is a part of Indonesian/Malay language.
I wasn't looking at the subtitles when I began a new game, and I immediately recognized the language when the narrator spoke, but it is indeed mixed with another language, probably Swahili like Samthere stated.

Source : myself, I'm not an Indonesian but I've lived there for 3 years, so I can speak some basics

Answer (score 0):

No it's not Malay!

It's called "Bahasa Indonesia" language. They used the local language from a specific tribe in Indonesia: that's why it differs in accent and some words. The local language has a lot of differences from the national language.

Comment: Do you have a source on this?

Comment: @Hendrawan - Unlikely based on the fact the accepted answer source says otherwise.

Comment: No it is definitely not an Indon language. It is clearly Malay, with correct pronunciation and mix with other language.

Answer (score -1):

It is a mix of mostly Bahasa Indonesia, Ternate and some other West Papuan sub-languages.

Comment: Your answer directly contradicts an existing answer.  Do you have a source for this?